# Set format of string in PyYaml output file?

Tags: python, string, styles, format, yaml

I want to save this dictionary

```
data = { yaml: { l: 'hi\nif x = y:\n  print z\n' } }
```

using Python in YAML. When I use `yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False)`, the output is:

```
yaml: 
  l: "hi\nif x = y:\n  print z\n"
```

but I know that YAML has this format:

```
yaml: 
  l:
    |
    hi
    if x = y:
      print z
```

What should I do to have the output in the above format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using YAML scalar:

[YAML Scalar](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Scalars)

```
import yaml
from collections import OrderedDict    

class literal(str): pass

def literal_presenter(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='|')
yaml.add_representer(literal, literal_presenter)

def ordered_dict_presenter(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_dict(data.items())
yaml.add_representer(OrderedDict, ordered_dict_presenter)

d_temp = OrderedDict(l=literal('hi\nif x = y:\n print z\n'))
d = OrderedDict(yaml=literal(yaml.dump(d_temp)))
print(yaml.dump(d))
```

**Output:**

```
 yaml: |
      l: |
        hi
        if x = y:
         print z
```

Hope it works for you...